# Div resized when its font size changed

Tags: html, css

Ok. So here's the code.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 4em;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.descriptio {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    font-size:0.8em;
}


<div clasa="list">
      <div class="ev-container">
          <div class="tempus"><p>T-ALFA</p></div>  
          <div class="locus"><p>TYPE</p></div>
          <div class="descriptio"><p>DESCRIPTION IS WHERE YOU FIND OUT</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

`.tempus` and `.locus` divs have `width:20%` . All have no margins and no paddings inherited from a div that encloses them.

For the love of truth... just why... just why... when font-size in `.descriptio` is `0.8em` it screws up the div size and the floating ?

Please tell me. I am about to throw my old, rusty and trustful laptop out the window.

## I CAME AND GOT AN ANSWER

Thanks @Steve Fenton for the answer. I've been fiddling for the first time in my life with css the past 2 days. I don't know what the people standardizing CSS/HTML etc are smoking but for sure I don't want to try.

I've been reading about the calc() function and how the standardization committee hates it. The "high" is high in them.

Comment: By screwing up you mean? what's ur desired output

Comment: 3 neatly left floated divs, all the same height. The height of descriptio changes. Much obliged.

Comment: `<div clasa="list">` is a typo ?!

Comment: @caramba Yes it is a typo. But fixing that typo didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] – jsfiddle, codepen or something.

Comment: no it will not solve your issue. You should update your question so there are no typos ... and check your code maybe there are more :)

Comment: How do you expect your output would be?

Comment: Why wouldn't the height change if the font-size changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height changes because you are using `em` height, and are effectively changing that by changing the font size.

One fix would be to move the font-size change to the paragraph:

```
.descriptio p {
    font-size: 0.8em; 
}
```

Now all three `div` elements have the same font size, so `4em` will equal the same height.

Comment: Sir, you solved my problem. I really don't understand why it works really. I set the size to all divs to 4em. So why would setting localy the font size in a div change the size of the div if it's 4em ?

Comment: It is `4em`, where `1em` is the size of the letter `m`... which was 20% smaller in one div because you set the size of the letter `m` (and all other letters) to `0.8m`. So if the font on a div was `16px`, then `4em` would be `4 x 16`.

Comment: Kind of convoluted how css works...

Comment: That's what makes it fun :) If this solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer - and maybe even up-vote it if you think it is well written. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: How do I accept the answer ? Kind of a noob around here... can't vote i need reputation

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your div's height is compared to the font size(you gave div height in em). Use height: 50px; for example instead and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

`em` is a unit of measure based on your current font size.

In your example, if the font-size of your div is 16px, the height will be 64px (16 x 4).

If you want a static height, use pixels instead.

As far as your `<div class="descriptio">` goes, the `60%` width is measured by the size of its container. It is not affected by font size.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm